# Build framework with bitcode

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks

Im trying to create an `universal framework` from one of the `targets` in my project. I have used a few scripts, I have found on the internet, but I have one problem - the final framework, doesn't seem to include `bitcode`. This is the script, that I'm using to create this framework:

```
UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR=${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-universal
RELEASE_DIR=${PROJECT_DIR}/build
TARGET="Observation"

mkdir -p "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR}"

xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -target "${TARGET}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build -sdk iphoneos
xcodebuild BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode -target "${TARGET}" ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO -configuration ${CONFIGURATION} BUILD_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}" BUILD_ROOT="${BUILD_ROOT}" clean build -sdk iphonesimulator

cp -R "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${TARGET}.framework" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR}/"

SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR="${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET}.framework/Modules/${TARGET}.swiftmodule/."
if [ -d "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" ]; then
    cp -R "${SIMULATOR_SWIFT_MODULES_DIR}" "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR}/${TARGET}.framework/Modules/${TARGET}.swiftmodule"
fi

lipo -create -output "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR}/${TARGET}.framework/${TARGET}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphonesimulator/${TARGET}.framework/${TARGET}" "${BUILD_DIR}/${CONFIGURATION}-iphoneos/${TARGET}.framework/${TARGET}"

cp -R "${UNIVERSAL_OUTPUT_DIR}/${TARGET}.framework" "${RELEASE_DIR}"
open "${RELEASE_DIR}"
```

And when I try to use it, I get this error:

```
ld: '/Users/homedudycz/Desktop/Test/Test/Observation.framework/Observation' does not contain bitcode. You must rebuild it with bitcode enabled (Xcode setting ENABLE_BITCODE), obtain an updated library from the vendor, or disable bitcode for this target. file '/Users/homedudycz/Desktop/Test/Test/Observation.framework/Observation' for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Can someone help me with this?